# How to show picker choose before button command in MVVM xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I have this code:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
<Label Text="Text:" FontSize="Medium" />
<Label Text="{Binding Material.Name}" d:Text="Item name" FontSize="Small"/>
<Label Text="Description:" FontSize="Medium" />
<Label Text="{Binding Material.Description}" d:Text="Item description" FontSize="Small"/>

<Picker x:Name="PocketSelector"
    Title="--Select--"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Pockets}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding PocketName}"
    SelectedItem="SelectedPocketName"/>

<Button x:Name="AddToButton"
    Text="Add To"
    Command="{Binding AddToPocketCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference PocketSelector}}"/>
```

If i press AddToButton then command go in view model - all ok, pattern MVVM is correct.
But how can i check (in pageview or in viewmodel) selected picker before pressed button?
I have two situations:
First Case - picker already selected. After that i press button and all ok.
Secont Case - picker selected item not selected yet. I press button and m**ust show picker window**. After that i choose item i picker ad command go to viewmodel (or i need second press button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement some view logic to enable/disable the button whenever the selection of picker changes. That would not break the MVVM pattern, because it is just view logic.

But a more elegant way is to have a changed ViewModel like

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private Material _material;
    private Pocket _selectedPocket;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Pocket> _pockets;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var canExecuteAddToPocketCommand = this
            .WhenAnyValue( e => e.SelectedPocket )
            .Select( e =>  e != null );

        AddToPocketCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(
            ExecuteAddToPocketCommandAsync,
            canExecuteAddToPocketCommand );

        Material = new Material { Name = "Material Name", Description = "Material Description" };

        _pockets = new ObservableCollection<Pocket>( Enumerable.Range( 1, 10 ).Select( id => new Pocket { PocketName = $"Pocket {id}" } ).ToList() );
        Pockets = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Pocket>( _pockets );
    }

    private async Task ExecuteAddToPocketCommandAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay( 250 );
        SelectedPocket = null;
    }

    public Material Material { get => _material; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _material, value ); }
    public ICollection<Pocket> Pockets { get; }

    // *** ADDED PROPERTY ***
    public Pocket SelectedPocket { get => _selectedPocket; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _selectedPocket, value ); }

    public ICommand AddToPocketCommand { get; }
}
```

The command now [reports itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged?view=netframework-4.8) if it can be executed or not and the view will enable/disable the control to represent that state.

The View itself can then be simplified to:

```
<StackLayout Padding="15" Spacing="20">
    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Text:" />
    <Label
        d:Text="Item name"
        FontSize="Small"
        Text="{Binding Material.Name}" />
    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Description:" />
    <Label
        d:Text="Item description"
        FontSize="Small"
        Text="{Binding Material.Description}" />

    <Picker
        Title="--Select--"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding PocketName}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Pockets}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPocket}" />

    <Button Command="{Binding AddToPocketCommand}" Text="Add To" />
</StackLayout>
```

---

FYI: The ViewModel uses the [NuGet Package ReactiveUI.XamForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReactiveUI.XamForms)

Comment: Thanks! But it is complicated to :))

Comment: Adding **one** property to the ViewModel is complicated? How would you name then the really complicated stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I make like this (MVVM goodbye) ):

```
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Проверка на наличие орговых предложений

        if(ViewModel.CurrentProduct.HaveOffer)
        {
            if (this.pickerOffer.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                //TODO Тут тоже классный костыль! Четко! Умеете, могете!
                //Button_Clicked вообще из параллельной вселенной сюда пришел
                ViewModel.CurrentOffer = ((ProductOffer)this.pickerOffer.SelectedItem);
                ViewModel.AddToCartCommand.Execute(ViewModel.CurrentProduct);
            }
            else
            {
                // Ничего не выбрано из орговых предложений
                // Необходимо выбраь
                this.pickerOffer.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewModel.AddToCartCommand.Execute(ViewModel.CurrentProduct);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer ,which will help more people .